# How to create spinner control with onclickitem

Tags: java, android, eclipse, onclicklistener, android-spinner

I m begginer of android  I need to create spinner control in my project with onclick  item when i m click item in spinner control move with another activity display various data like in my project click bus name in spinner it display route info,time,distance .note :i have 100+ bus name so every bus didnt create differnt activity is not possible give me example coding

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `OnItemSelectedListener` with your `Spinner`.

**Here is an example:**

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.your_spinner);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
            String item = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            // Do something
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Here is a complete [tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_spinner_control.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
    // Spinner element
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    // Spinner click listener
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    Lis<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    lines.add("line 1");
    lines.add("line 2");
    lines.add("line 3");
    lines.add("line 4");

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lines);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

and then you can add it as your listener:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // On selecting a spinner item
    String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

    // Showing selected spinner item
    Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

 @Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
}
```